# Hibernate Search and Relations

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, relation, hibernate-search

I have an object called `MyItemBean` which can have 0 or more associated `KeywordBean` objects.  The resulting classes look like this:

```
@Entity
public class MyItemBean {

   ...stuff...

   @ManyToMany(targetEntity = KeywordBean.class, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinTable(name = "tbl_item_keyword", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "keyword_id"))
   private List<KeywordBean> keywords = null;

   ...more stuff...
}

@Entity
public class KeywordBean {

   ...stuff...

   private String value=null;

   ...more stuff...
}
```

I'm using JBoss Seam/Hibernate Search to index these objects so I can perform search queries against them.  I'd like to be able to search for `MyItemBean` instances with a given keyword value.  This relation, however, is unidirectional because I apply `KeywordBean` objects to more than just `MyItemBean`.  I've looked in the Hibernate Search documentation for examples on how to index relations, but all of the examples they provide are bi-directional.  Can anyone tell me what annotations I need to apply on `MyItemBean.keywords` to index the keyword values properly?

Comment: Your `*Bean` is not specially a Bean. It is rather a value object (`*VO`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The annotation to use is *IndexedEmbedded*. It works fine with unidirectional associations as well. A problem can occur if you are changing the value of *KeywordBean* Hibernate Search does not have a way to update the index for the *MyItemBean* instances which reference the changed *KeywordBean*. In bidirectional relations you can use *@ContainedIn* to fix this problem, but you don't really need this. Provided on your usecase this index updating constraint might not be an issue. Maybe your *KeywordBean* is not changing. Or if it changes you can re-index all *KeywordBean*s which are affected manually.

--Hardy

Comment: So where does the @IndexEmbedded annotation go?  Would it go on KeywordBean at class-level?  Or MyItemBean at property level for keywords?

Comment: It belongs onto the keyword property in MyItemBean